# how to sort a Dictionary in list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I had Question in python
Imagine a list with dictionaries in it
how can we sort it by a value in dictionary ?

Imagine this list :

```
lst = [
    {
        "a" : 3,
        "b" : 2
    },
    {
        "a" : 1,
        "b" : 4
    },
    {
        "a" : 2,
        "b" : 3
    }
]
```

how can we sort this list by value of "a" in each dictionary (python)
i mean i want this list at the end :

```
lst = [
    {
        "a" : 1,
        "b" : 4
    },
    {
        "a" : 2,
        "b" : 3
    },
    {
        "a" : 3,
        "b" : 2
    }
]
```

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: @alphaBetaGamma your link is not the same logic

Comment: Use 'get()' method as follows:

    my_list = [{"a": 3, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": 10}, {"a": 2, "b": 3}]
    k=sorted(my_list,key=lambda x :x.get('a'))
    print(k)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could provide a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=lambda#lambda-expressions) key to [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> lst = [
...     {
...         "a" : 3,
...         "b" : 2
...     },
...     {
...         "a" : 1,
...         "b" : 4
...     },
...     {
...         "a" : 2,
...         "b" : 3
...     }
... ]
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda d: d["a"])
[{'a': 1, 'b': 4}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}, {'a': 3, 'b': 2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach, use the `key` argument with [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [{"a": 3, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": 4}, {"a": 2, "b": 3}]

res = sorted(lst, key=itemgetter("a"))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 4}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}, {'a': 3, 'b': 2}]
```

From the documentation on `itemgetter`:

> Return a callable object that fetches item from its operand using the
> operand’s **getitem**() method. If multiple items are specified,
> returns a tuple of lookup values. For example:
>
> After f = itemgetter(2), the call f(r) returns r[2].
> After g =
> itemgetter(2, 5, 3), the call g(r) returns (r[2], r[5], r[3]).